# Is it possible to temporarily comment out part of a post?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, editing, markdown

Scenario ([true story](https://mathoverflow.net/q/378880/41291)): after posting something I became doubtful about certain claim there,
so I want to hide it until I clarify my doubts.

Of course I could just move that part to a temporary file, but it would be much more convenient to have it in place, ready for further processing. Presently I have put it in `<del>...</del>` but this is not quite what I want, since it creates impression that this part is definitely wrong, while actually I simply don't know yet whether it is or not.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hide the part in HTML comments:

```
BEFORE <!-- this is something I want to hide --> AFTER
```

produces:

> BEFORE  AFTER

---

Spoilers would be another option, but perhaps less clear in conveying the intention.

```
>! This is something I want to hide
```

produces

> This is something I want to hide

Answer (score 13):

Since other answers mention HTML comments, let me clarify that using them is only a commonly employed *custom* on SE sites, which just abuses the fact that it works *by accident*.

In reality, the Stackexchange Markdown parser **does not support** HTML comments. What actually happens is that the initial `<` followed by unrecognized content is parsed as an *invalid HTML tag*, which makes the parser strip everything up to the next `>` character. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120418.

One consequence is that these “comments” don’t obey the syntactic rules governing actual HTML comments: for example, a “comment” such as `<!-- asdf <br> qwer -->` stops early at the first `>`, and the  `qwer -->` part is visible in the output:  qwer -->.

Another consequence is that there is nothing special about `<!--`: you can use any other invalid (or unsupported) HTML tag for the same purpose, for example `<this is my comment: fk dsajk fdsjka hfjdks fhjkhadsa>`:

Comment: Is <script> supported on SE? :)

Comment: @joro You can find list of the supported HTML tags here: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777) Since your asking about <script>, maybe [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) are what you have in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Since Stack Exchange allows also some limited use of html, you can use `<!---`...`--->` to make a "comment" inside the post. Check the [source code of this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/4782/revisions) for an example.

I will add that I have seen warnings that mixing MarkDown and HTML too much might sometimes lead to problems, I do not know much about types of are known for html comments.

EDIT: If I understood correctly the information from the link provided in Emil Jeřábek's comment, HTML comments aren't *officially* supported. So one probably should not rely on the fact that they will always work. (On the other hand, if they are used just a temporary workaround, maybe that isn't that terrible.) See also: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777)

EDIT2: In the meantime, Emil Jeřábek added [an answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4781/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-comment-out-part-of-a-post/4785#4785) where he explains this in detail.

---

This post mentions problems with `>` inside the comment: [> is closing HTML comments without a -​- delimiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120415). The same issue is mentioned here: [Can't Seem to comment out a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123661). (And in both cases it is mentioned that it is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design) and not a bug.)

Let us try some test concerning this.

You can see that the following input does not hide everything:

```
We'll try both $a<b$ and $a>b$ (with and without dollars):  
<!-- a<b -->  
<!-- a>b --> 
<!-- $a<b$ -->   
<!-- $a>b$ -->  
<!-- Link to [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4781) -->
```

We'll try both $a<b$ and $a>b$ (with and without dollars):

b -->

Comment: Thank you! @Glorfindel was one minute quicker, and also provided another option, so...

Comment: Yes, Stack Exchange allows some limited use of html, but comments are *not* part of the allowed use. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120418.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Just to clarify what your comment (and animuson's answer you oinked) is saying - the gist of it that using HTML comments is *not officially supported*. (And the fact that they actually work - at least in the examples posted in the answeres here - should be considered a lucky accident, byt is not by any means guaranteed.) Is that more-or-less correct?

Comment: I will add that I was trying to find some kind of official documentation about this when I was writing the answer. And I saw that HTML comments are not mentioned here: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777) However, since I saw them used on the site several times, I thought that it might be just an oversight that they are missing in that list.

Comment: Yes, HTML comments sort-of work by accident: the parser removes them not because they are comments, but because it considers them invalid HTML tags, which also means they behave syntactically in a different way than proper HTML comments. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

`$$`

`% You can hide your drafts inside the math environment, using the percentage symbol. Click edit on my answer to see it in action.`

`$$`

$$
% Assume the Riemann Hypothesis is false.
% Then clearly... hmm.
$$

Comment: Although, when you refresh the page you briefly see the hidden text flashing...

Comment: Lovely solution!

Answer (score 1):

"posting something"... Do you mean  a question or an answer?  I occasionally to the following with my answers.
**"Delete" it, until I am ready, then "undelete" it.**
I have never tried this on my questions, but someone once told me that I cannot do that with questions.

Comment: The part I want to hide in this particular case is only a small portion of the post, the rest is perfectly sane. And I believe this can happen equally with questions and with answers.

Comment: Concerning the fact that it is not possible to edit self-deleted questions, I was given this link as a place where it is (in some way) documented: [Couple of issues with Roomba Turbocharging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178760#179555). And I can confirm that when I tried it myself - I was able to edit self-deleted answers, but not self-deleted questions. (This restriction does not apply to questions which were deleted by other users, not the OP.)

Comment: In connection to this, it is worth adding that editing a deleted answer bumps the question - which might be not desired. (This related feature request was marked as status-by-design: [Stop an edited deleted answer from bumping the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42066).) Of course, this is moot if *both* the question and the answer are deleted.